# chrome extension:I am doing a contextMenu.How can I send the selection to background.html when I click on the contextmenu?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to use the script below to get the HTML of the selection

```
  var range=window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var container = document.createElement('div');
    container.appendChild(range.cloneContents());
    return container.innerHTML;
```

If use message passing how should I write in my contentscript.js and backgroud.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background page:

```
// Request handler
function onRequest(request, sender, callback) {
    doSomethingWith(request.data);    
}

// Request handler registration
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(onRequest);
```

Content script (assuming the HTML of the selection has been stored in the *selectedHTML* variable):

```
// Sends data to the background page
chrome.extension.sendRequest({data: selectedHTML});
```